# Can I use jQuery's deferred.pipe method to modify arguments supplied to resolved/fail callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I'd like to be able to use jQuery's Deferred object to operate loading data via Backbone Collections and Models.  Is there any way I can modify the arguments provided to the done and fail callbacks to include the Model or Collection instance?  I'm envisioning something like the following:

```
var _sync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function() {
    var jqXhr = _sync.apply(this, arguments);

    var self = this;
    return jqXhr.pipe(function() {
        var cbArgs = [self];
        cbArgs.push.apply(cbArgs, arguments);
        return cbArgs; 
    }
}

...
var c = new Backbone.Collection();
c.url = "/path/to/resources";
c.fetch().then(function(collection, data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    // do stuff with collection
});
```

Of course, since filter is returning an array, the done callback is invoked with an array, rather than the enumerated arguments.  As far as I can see, pipe can only modify provided arguments, not add.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit:  This is a very simplified example; since a closure is created over the original collection, I could just operate on that.  However, the use case is that multiple Backbone Views might rely on the same data being fetched, so I'd like to be able to just supply the jQuery Deferred object to these views, rather than both the Deferred and the collection instance.

Another Edit:  Posted a solution below, but any other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found I can accomplish this by having the .pipe method return a new $.Deferred that is immediately resolved using the modified arguments:

```
var _sync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function() {
    var jqXhr = _sync.apply(this, arguments);

    var self = this;
    var deferred = jqXhr.pipe(function() {
        var cbArgs = [self];
        cbArgs.push.apply(cbArgs, arguments);
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        return deferred.resolve.apply(deferred, cbArgs);
    });
    return $.extend(true, jqXhr, deferred);
};
```

Comment: Edited to extend the original jqXhr with the new $.Deferred, maintaining support for all AJAX-specific methods (.success, .abort, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

A solution very similar to your answer, but without pipe, since you don't actually need to filter the results: I directly return a new deferred from Backbone.sync instead of piping a resolved deferred

```
Backbone.originalSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var xhr = Backbone.originalSync.call(this, method, model, options);

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    xhr.done(function() {
        var cbArgs = [model].concat(_.toArray(arguments));
        dfd.resolve.apply(dfd, cbArgs);
    });
    xhr.fail(function() {
        var cbArgs = [model].concat(_.toArray(arguments));
        dfd.reject.apply(dfd, cbArgs);
    });

    return dfd;
};
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d8FqA/

A simpler variation if you're willing to have `this` bound to the model/collection in your callbacks, which leaves the function signatures untouched:

```
Backbone.originalSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var xhr = Backbone.originalSync.call(this, method, model, options);

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    xhr.done(function() {
        dfd.resolveWith(model, arguments);
    });
    xhr.fail(function() {
        dfd.rejectWith(model, arguments);
    });

    return dfd;
};

var c=new Backbone.Collection();
c.fetch().done(function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8FqA/1/

which leads us to pass the model as context to the Ajax request :

```
Backbone.originalSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options={}) ;
    options.context = model;
    return Backbone.originalSync.call(this, method, model, options);
};

var c=new Backbone.Collection();
c.fetch().done(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8FqA/2/

Comment: Interesting... definitely a similar solution.  One thing I think both solutions could benefit from would be extending the original jqXhr object with the new deferreds, such that the response from Backbone.sync does not change at all (with the exception of the promise)  ex.) return $.extend(true, xhr, dfd);

Comment: @philm I think we can simplify things a lot by using the context in the callbacks and leave the xhr object alone. Updated my answer with a solution

Comment: One of the issues this presents is that if we are waiting for multiple deferreds to be resolved, then which collection will the context be bound to? ex:) var col1 = new Bacbkone.Collection(), col2 = new Backbone.Collection();  $.when(col1.fetch(), col2.fetch()).then(function() { ... });

Comment: Seems like a strange pattern for aggregating the contexts...  Given that waiting on multiple asynchronous actions is a common pattern we've been trying to solve, I'm more in favor of providing the model/collection as a function parameter.